# Deleting times in a dataframe based on the current time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have the following data frame denoted by dfm.

My aim is to eliminate the rows with the time within 2.5hrs of the current time.

|  | time | A | year | time2 | new_column | dateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 06/0818:00 | 32 | 21/ | 21/06/0818:00 | 2021-06-08 18:00:00 | 18:00:00 |
| 1 | 06/0819:00 | 6 | 21/ | 21/06/0819:00 | 2021-06-08 19:00:00 | 19:00:00 |
| 2 | 06/0920:00 | 5 | 21/ | 21/06/0920:00 | 2021-06-09 20:00:00 | 20:00:00 |
| 3 | 06/0921:00 | 6 | 21/ | 21/06/0921:00 | 2021-06-09 21:00:00 | 21:00:00 |
| 4 | 06/0922:00 | 41 | 21/ | 21/06/0922:00 | 2021-06-09 22:00:00 | 22:00:00 |
| 5 | 06/0923:00 | 41 | 21/ | 21/06/0923:00 | 2021-06-09 23:00:00 | 23:00:00 |
| 6 | 06/0900:00 | 38 | 21/ | 21/06/0900:00 | 2021-06-09 00:00:00 | 00:00:00 |
| 7 | 06/0901:00 | 37 | 21/ | 21/06/0901:00 | 2021-06-09 01:00:00 | 01:00:00 |

I started off by making sure new_column was a datetime rather than an object using:

```
pd.to_datetime(dfm['new_column'])
dfm.dtypes
```

which returned the type datetime64[ns] for new_column

I then ran the following code to denote the current time:

```
import datetime;

ct = datetime.datetime.now()
t = print("current time:-", ct)
```

The next part I'm having trouble with is creating a code that uses the current time to eliminate any times that are within 2.5hrs of the current time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, change ct into pd.datetime. I am not certain about the compatibility between python datetime and pandas datetime. You can basically filter after that.

For instance, code I use for changing now into pd.datetime is:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
now = datetime.datetime.now()
date = [now]
df_today = pd.DataFrame(data=date)
df_today.columns = ['date']
df_today['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_today['date'])
ct = df_today.iloc[0,0]
```

and then filter out what you want using similar syntax as below:

```
dfm = dfm[dfm['new_column'] <= ct + timedelta(hours=2.5)]
dfm = dfm[dfm['new_column'] >= ct - timedelta(hours=2.5)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like

```
time_range = datetime.timedelta(hours=2.5)
dfm.drop(dfm.index([dfm['time'] < ct - time_range]))
dfm.drop(dfm.index([dfm['time'] < ct + time_range]))
```